# Kohana front end , Wordpress back end

Tags: php, wordpress, kohana, blogs

I love Kohana code, I don't love Wordpress code. I need to upgrade a blog to have a custom theme, very custom with Grid style blog roll (like Pinterest) and Traditional Blog Roll, and fully responsive for all devices.

I was thinking of keeping the Back end on Wordpress as it currently is (maybe on a different subdomain), and then writing a custom Kohana front end, which queries the WP database and makes up the pages. All blogging happens on WP, all pages that readers see are run as a Kohana site. No user sign up required, there is only one user (the blogger)

Am I crazy? Has anyone tried this? Is there anything to watch out for?

(Yes, what I need to do probably could be done by an experienced WP developer, but I'm not him, and I'm gonna have to maintain this for years to come).

Comment: IMO I think you're at least a little bit mad. Kohana is an entire framework, as is Wordpress. You're better off putting up with Wordpress for this. You can't cherry pick Kohana's front end and nail it onto Wordpress

Comment: Thanks, any specific reason why you think I can't have my cake and eat it?

Comment: Because Kohana is (was) a port of Codeigniter, not CakePHP `;)`. On a more serious note, it's because you'll find it hard to integrate Kohana with Wordpress. You'll spend less time and effort going with either one or the other. I know how you feel about disliking something you have to work with, but sometimes it's easier to stick it out with pants code

Comment: Thanks, I understand... but so far I'm not deterred... but I know there's a pretty good chance I'll end up agreeing with you after a few days of coding. hehe. Anyway, I've poked around the WP tables, and they don't look to complicated to write queries on. After working with strict MVC, I can't go back. I'd rather just pay someone to build the WP theme for me if it comes to that.

Answer (score 0):

Kohana is a front-end framework, WordPress is a blogging platform, they don’t play well together. You *could* write a website with Kohana than uses WordPress functions to query the WordPress database, but that’s just stupid and will lead to overhead, spaghetti code, and a pain in the ass at a later date when you realise what a stupid set-up it is.

WordPress’s front-end is perfectly capable at doing what you want to do. I don’t see why you would want to use an entirely different framework—it’s not going to give you an benefits.

Comment: can you please check this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934551/access-data-from-kohana-to-wordpress which is related to inegration of kohana with wordpress